# Rails: Working with a large set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some rake scripts that operate on collections of hundreds of thousands of items.

Often, my server runs out of memory and the script crashes. I assume that this is because my code looks like this:

`Asset.where(:archived => false).each { |asset| asset.action!  }`

As far as I can tell, Rails fetches the entire set into memory, and then iterates through each instance.

My server doesn't seem to be happy loading 300,000 instances of `Asset` at once, so in order to reduce the memory requirements I've had to resort to something like this:

```
collection = Asset.where(:archived => false) # ActiveRecord::Relation
while collection.count > 0
  collection.limit(1000).each { |asset| asset.action! }
end
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem very clean. It gets even worse when the action doesn't remove the items from the set, and I have to keep track with `offset`s too. Does anyone have suggestions as to a better way of partitioning the data or holding onto the relation longer, and only loading rows as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) method is designed to help in these situations. It'll

```
Asset.where(:archived => false).find_each(:batch_size=>500) do |asset|
  asset.stuff
end
```

by default, the batch size is 1000